# How to use early-hint in HAProxy?

Tags: http-headers, haproxy, http2, preload

I am trying to get early hints to work in HAProxy, but no luck so far.

Surprisingly so, as it ought not be overly complicated (supposedly)...

```
frontend mysite_frontend_ssl
        mode http
        bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/mysite.com.pem alpn h2,http/1.1
        http-request early-hint Link "<https://static.mysite.com/test.css>; rel=preload; as=style"
        http-request early-hint Link "<https://static.mysite.com/test.js>; rel=preload; as=script"
        option forwardfor
        default_backend mysite_backend
```

I am using Chrome 109 for testing (and Chrome supports early hints since v103)

HAProxy is version 2.5.5, which was released in 2022/03 (and HAProxy supports early hints since 2018 if I'm not mistaken)

So, why can't I see the early hints and the preloads in my Network tab in DevTools?

Any idea? I literally can't find ANYTHING about early hints with HAProxy on the Internet. No tutorials, no explanations (except [the announcement](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/haproxy-1-9-has-arrived/) in 2018 and the [small paragraph](https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/hapee/latest/onepage/#4.2-http-request%20early-hint) in the docs). Nothing.

Aren't people supposed to be using it all over the world? Now I'm confused...

**Bonus question:** any idea how to have different preload links / early-hints for different "locations"? ("location" as in nginx, e.g. an URL regex of sorts). Should I only add an "if" condition after the early-hint? For example, for my homepage I'd like to early-hint a few scripts and images and fonts, and for the catalog page I'd like other resources to be preloaded. I know how to do selective push with nginx, but alas it's complicated with HAProxy in front of it, plus it's not possible for cross-domain, so I ought to do it (preload I mean, not push) with HAProxy.

Thanks everyone! :)